# woocommerce one page checkout, redirect to cart when error

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, checkout

My cart is merge with checkout using WooCommerce Single Page Checkout.

If an error occurs in the checkout (ex:shipping_address1 is not filled), I want to redirect to cart (because that page contains cart+checkout) and not checkout page.

In class-wc-checkout.php, I see "public function process_checkout()" and "validate_checkout" in it. I understand that "send_ajax_failure_response()" is called but it reload checkout.

What should I change to reload cart page ?

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "WC_get_checkout_url" with "WC_get_cart_url" in form-checkout.php (that you can personnilize in your child theme).

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( WC_get_cart_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

May be the hook some lines before could work (tried in my site without success).